# Website that pulls information from a running desktop application

Tags: javascript, python, web

So, I have a website which I'm using Javascript on and a desktop application written in python. I am wanting the web page to pull data from the python app when it's loaded without having to go through too many loops. So, if possible, how could I setup Python to send the page information when it requests it? I know this might be a backwards way of doing it but I'm curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `without having to go through too many loops` I'm assuming this means you want it simple. The easiest way I can think of is setting 2 endpoints (urls):

- One for asking if it's time to send the information
- Another one for actually sending it

In this case you would have to make a loop where the python app will keep asking the website if it's time to send the information.

If you **really** need the website to decide when to "pull" the information, you may want to have a look in web sockets. They provide a way to create a connection between server and client where the server can request (or send) information when it's needed (the decision in this case doesn't have to come from the client). But this is assuming you can keep a connection open.

If you want to go down the websockets path, maybe it's worth checking out this project: http://socket.io/

I believe there are good clients for python.